# Save UIImage array in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I want to put a `UIImage` array into `UserDefaults` and then retrieve it. After that set the retrieved images in an image view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily save your image in documentDirectory as below:

`let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let fileURL = documentDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(yourImageName)`

and then, you can give your image to UserDefaults

Answer (score 4):

First of all that is not ideal way to save image in user default but if you want you can do following things

**Save**

```
let imageData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: placesArray)
UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "images")
```

**Retrieve**

```
       let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "images") as? NSData

        if let imageData = imageData {
            let imageArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: imageData as Data) as? [UIImage]!
            print(placesArray)
        }
```

Note: You should save your image in document directory and then save that name array to user default.

Save image in document directory

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(){
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("apple.jpg")
        let image = UIImage(named: "apple.jpg")
        print(paths)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFileAtPath(paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
```

**Retrieve image**

```
func getImage(name : String){
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imagePAth){
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
        }else{
            print("No Image")
        }
    }

func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: Work fine on Swift 4.2

Answer (score 0):

That's really bad idea if you really going to do that. You should save image in **DocumentDirectory** and save images name in **NSUserDefaults**.

```
func saveImages(images:[UIImage]) {

     let fileManager = FileManager.default
     let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString) 
     var imagesNames = [String]()


    do {

        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path as String){
            try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path as String, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }

     for (index,image) in images.enumarated() {
        let imageName = "Image\(index).jpg"
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        if fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths.appending("/\(file)") as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil) {
         imagesNames.append(imageName)
        }
      }
     let storage = UserDefaults.standard
     storage.set(imagesNames, forKey: "imagesArray")
     storage.synchronize()

    }catch{
        //Throw Error
    } 
}
```

Comment: but i have multiple images in array, which want show in imageview so i can in DocumentDirectory

Comment: can you share your code here because i am new in development

Comment: Check out. I modified Answer.

Comment: And after set in user default

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach, convert UIImages to NSData. Then add image data’s into an NSArray. Then save the NSArray into UserDefault.
When retrieving the NSArray from UserDefault,use ImageWithData method to render UIImage from the NSArray’s each elements.
This is the easiest process if you really one to use UserDefaults for your purpose. Try this yourself.